# How to Show Interstitial Admob after 5 secs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, interstitial

I have issues implementing interstitial timed ads with my flutter source code. I want to implement where it shows an ad 5 seconds after each page loads. I have issues implementing interstitial timed ads with my flutter source code. I want to implement where it shows an ad every 5 seconds on each page load. Please help

**am using the code below:**

```
import 'package:cirilla/service/ads_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'dart:async';

const int maxFailedLoadAttempts = 3;

class CirillaAdsInterstitial extends StatefulWidget {
  const CirillaAdsInterstitial({Key? key, required this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  _CirillaAdsInterstitialState createState() => _CirillaAdsInterstitialState();
}

class _CirillaAdsInterstitialState extends State<CirillaAdsInterstitial> {
  int _interstitialLoadAttempts = 0;

  // TODO: Add _interstitialAd
  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Add these lines to launch timer on start of the app
    _timerForInter = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), (result) {
      _interstitialAd = createInterstitialAd()..load();
    });

    // TODO: Implement _loadInterstitialAd()
    void _createInterstitialAd() {
      InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: AdService.interstitialAdUnitId,
        request: AdRequest(),
        adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
            _interstitialAd = ad;
            _interstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            _interstitialLoadAttempts += 1;
            _interstitialAd = null;
            if (_interstitialLoadAttempts >= maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
              _createInterstitialAd();
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }


    void _showinterstitialAd() {
      if (_interstitialAd != null) {
        _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          ad.dispose();
          _createInterstitialAd();
        }, onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
        ad.dispose();
        _createInterstitialAd();
        });
        _interstitialAd!.show();
      }
    }

  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timerForInter.cancel();
    _interstitialAd?.dispose();

  }
}
```

am using the flutter language pls help

Comment: showing an interstitial ad every 5 sec is NOT RECOMMENDED. ``DON'T DO IT UNLESS YOU WANT YOUR ACCOUNT GETTING BANNED !!``

Comment: an interstitial ad should only be shown usually when navigating to/from a page or before/after an event start/end.

Comment: I made a mistake I meant i want it to load once, 5 secs after the pagescreen loads

Comment: Instead of ``_timerForInter = Timer.periodic(...)`` use ``_timerForInter = Timer(...)``

Comment: ``Timer.periodic()`` is used to repeat events after a specified time while ``Timer()`` is used to run an event once after the specified time.

Comment: Got that thanks. But it still doesn't load the interstitial

Comment: ALways test with test ad ids provided by Google https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads or check logcat for any possible issue